# How to communicate UI state changes between React components with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

as far as I understood Redux it is about keeping all state of the UI in one store (to be able to reproduce certain states easily and to have no side-effects). You can manipulate the state via triggering actions which trigger reducers.

I am currently writing a small blog-like app where you can simply create and edit posts. I have a dialog for creating a post, roughly the `render` method of the `App` component returns something like this:

```
<div>
    <AppBar ... />
    <PostFormDialog
      addPost={actions.addPost}
      ref="postFormDialog" />
    <PostList
      posts={posts}
      actions={actions} />
</div>
```

My question is: should the state of the dialog (opened or closed) be part of the state object of the App component? And should therefore opening and closing the dialog be triggered via an action instead of doing something like the following:

```
onTriggerCreatePostDialog(e) {
    this.refs.postFormDialog.show();
}
```

where `onTriggerCreatePostDialog` is triggered via some click listener on a "create" button or so.

It seems a little bit strange to me to do it via an actions because is introduces kind of an "indirection".

However, assuming that I want to reuse the dialog for the edit action, I must be able to open the dialog from elements which are deeper in the component structure, for example from a `Post` component which is a child of the `PostList` component. What I could do is pass the `onTriggerCreatePostDialog` function down the hierarchy via the `props` property, but that seems cumbersome to me...

So int the end is is also about communicating between components which are not in a direct parent-child relationship. Are there other options? Should I somehow utilise a global event bus? I am quite unsure currently.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that you are on the right path. The docs can be a bit tricky at first, but I can tell you how my team and I are using the implementation.

To address your first question; if the state is specific to a component then we keep that state with the component. An example of this would be a panel that pages records locally --- nothing else needs to be aware of that behavior. So in this instance we wouldn't trigger a redux action when the page changed, that would be handled internally within the component structure using refs.

Our redux state is comprised primarily of data collected via xhr requests or from a shared state. An example of shared state would be managing a time range among multiple components that use that range to display data. In this instance we would trigger a redux action; update the date state with whatever it was changed to (while also updating some other state items via xhr) and then ultimately that gets back to the components and they re-render.

With that said, triggering actions via refs is totally acceptable, it's just about what the specific use case is.

To address your second question; redux recommends using the [Smart & Dumb](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) component concept. So you are right that you would pass a function down the tree for the dumb components to utilize.

We utilize mapDispatchToProps in our [connect](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) setup. So basically you pass a function that returns an object of function "dispatchers". You will be able to access those functions directly in your smart component's `this.props`.

Example of mapDispatchToProps

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    myAction: () => dispatch(actions.myAction()),
  };
}
```

So that works 99% of the time, but I've run into some corner cases where we do use a global event bus, so don't be afraid to utilize both while attempting to stick to the Smart / Dumb component method as much as possible.

As a side note, I would recommend using [reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) to map your redux state to the smart component. You can also find other great redux resources [here](https://github.com/xgrommx/awesome-redux) (there are several things listed that we use).

Comment: What about triggering Redux actions for sibling components? Let's say you want one Redux action in sibling A that updates the store to be acknowledged and trigger the props to be accessed in sibling B's connect. Would you just have the connect in the parent component that has sibling A and B as children? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The state for the dialog should be in the redux store, triggered by actions. whether it should be rendered should be determined by checking that state in the redux store.

`App.render()` should be something like this:

```
render() {
  const { showDialog } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar ... />
      { showDialog ? <PostFormDialog ... /> : false }
      <PostList ... />
    </div>
  );
}
```

where `mapStateToProps` would be something like `state => {{ showDialog: state.showDialog }}`

In terms of delivering the action creator, passing it down the props tree is probably the correct way to do it unless you have some good location where it makes sense to have another smart component.

Comment: Assume the dialog is not modal. Initially it is not shown and its state is managed like you propose. I click a button, `showDialog` becomes truthy and this dialog is shown. Now, if I would click somewhere else than the dialog, it is closed again, but `showDialog` is not manipulated accordingly, unless I explicitly handle that case in `PostFormDialog`. That is just one example where the handling of the state of the dialog gets cumbersome, in my opinion. Would you do it like that anyway?

Comment: Regarding the smart component: would it maybe be reasonable to introduce another smart component to manage the state of the modal dialog, for example? Assuming the dialog can be used for creating a new post AND editing existing ones. Furthermore you have to handle things like "clearing" the dialog after successful creation/editing and so on...

Comment: this approach will work, but it will also break any dialog appearance/disappearance animation, won't it? Since the parent component is been re-rendered, the dialog will be removed from screen instantly. I wonder what the best workaround for that?