# React/Redux: Communicate between router and dumb components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, backbone.js, react-router

Our router handles navigation and page transitioning. After the page has finished transitioning, an event must be sent to deep dumb components, for example, our `<AppBody>` which manages an endless scroller. The endless scroller can only initialize when the page has finished transitioning because it performs DOM manipulation.

My question is what is the best way to communicate between the router and dumb components?

In Backbone, we used to trigger a function on the view that was just transitioned to, `view.show()`. In React, it seems there are 2 options, neither of which are great.

1. Update the props of the smart component with `isPageTransitionFinished={true}`, which gets sent down until it hits the dumb component that needs that property.
2. Update the router's state in the Redux store. The hard part here is figuring out which smart component is active and should then set `isPageTransitionFinished={true}`.

Comment: Which router are you using? Is this something of your own creation?

Comment: We're using Backbone's router. Eventually we'll switch to https://github.com/rackt/redux-router, but even so I'm curious as to how communication happens there.

Comment: I answered a similar question in depth here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570141/how-to-communicate-ui-state-changes-between-react-components-with-redux/33571141#33571141 - I think ultimately you're going to follow the smart to dumb component hierarchy (especially if you're using redux) or you can use an event bus